# Is it possible for a custom asp.net control to load types at design time from the assembly hosting the control?

Tags: reflection, assemblies, design-time

I have a custom server control for asp.net.  One of the properties available to it is a generic object.  That generic object has custom attributes that are read and used to customize the rendering of the control.

At run time, this is no problem, since all I need to do is find all the attributes on the instance that gets passed into the control.

However, just as the "DataSource" member of controls can call up a list of object types at design time, I would like to be able to bring up a list of types in the host assembly.  There is no need for actual instances, since I'm rendering based on attributes.

This is an example property from the host control:

```
[Browsable(true)]
[TypeConverter(typeof(TheObjectConverter))]
public object TheObject
{
    get { return _theObject; }
    set { SetTheObject(value); }
}
```

What I want to have happen is to have TheObjectConverter be able to load the assembly of the host page for the control.

None of the following seem to work

```
.GetReferencedAssemblies();
.GetExecutingAssembly();
.GetCallingAssembly();
.GetEntryAssembly();
.GetAssembly();
```

I even a full recursion against .GetReferencedAssemblies(), with no luck.  It seems I am unable to load the assembly of the control's host at design time.  Is that correct, or is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean they don't seem to work?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: Nope, I simply do not get the host assembly.  I get what appears to be Visual Studio's assembly, the control's assembly, etc.  But not the assembly of the page which is hosting the control at design time.